# Execution of code following catch block in java

Tags: java, exception

If an exception is caught, is the code that follows the exception executed? That is, after the `catch {...}` block.

```
{
    .....

    try {
        .....
    }
    catch (some exception se) {
        .....
    }

    .....

}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it for yourself?  Then you can report back and tell us all what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule yes (because you have caught the exception an dealt with it), but it depends what you do in the `catch` block (i.e. do you re-throw the exception?).

Comment: ... or return in some other way, or do a labelled `break`... Note that a `finally` clause executes even if one of those cases does apply.

Comment: Yep, didn't list all the possible things you could do in the block, cos I'd probably miss one ;-) `exit()`, `return` and `throw` are the most obvious.

Comment: Agreed. Mostly I wanted to make sure the querant was also aware of `finally`, since if they're asking this question they probably need that answer too.

Answer (score 0):

If the catch block returns, breaks (while in loop), throws a runtime exception or issues System.exit - no. Otherwise, the code should go through. I'm sure there are some factors I'm forgetting here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ...
    try {
        // Code block 1
    }
    catch (some execption se) {
        // Code block 2: run if there is exception in Code block 1
    }
    // This block will run if there is no exception/return/break/Sytem.exit() in Code block 2
```

You should read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html